# tensorflow code other than placeholder depends on batch size

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to TF. As an experiment I tried to modify the MNIST example, to implement a nonlinearity directly rather than using a predefined function.

The MNIST input data appears in the program as a tensor of size (10,784) where 10 is the batch size.  When this data is passed through my (modified) program, I get a shape error ("must have same rank") unless the rest of the code *also* references the batch size.  This is contrary to what I expect from tutorials, where it is implied that the batch size need only be considered for Placeholders, and can be generally ignored othersize. I had expected that most of the code could be written as if it is processing one datapoint at a time.

Here is the relevant part of the code.  mkmodule is called from a modified version of inference() in mnist.py (from the provided example) which in turn is called from fully_connected_feed.py.  The `theinput` argumet to mkmodule() is a batch of images, size (10,784).

```
def mknonlin(theinput,nactive):
    print('theinput shape vs nactive',theinput.get_shape(), nactive)
    a = tf.Variable(tf.ones([nactive]),name='a')
    c = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([nactive]))
    amul = tf.mul(a,(theinput-c),name='mul-a')
    zeros = tf.zeros([nactive])
    print('a',a.get_shape(), 'c',c.get_shape(),   'amul', amul.get_shape())
    result = tf.select(tf.greater(theinput,c), amul, zeros)
    return result

def mkmodule(thename,theinput,insize,outsize):
    print('module',thename,'input shape=',theinput,insize,'output size=',outsize)
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([insize,outsize], stddev=1.), name='W')
    activation = mknonlin(tf.matmul(theinput,W), outsize)
    return activation
```

The sprit of the algorithm is to multiply by the weight matrix W of size (784,32), then
pass the activations through an elementwise nonlinearity that is zero if the activation is less
than constant `c` and increases linearly otherwise, represented by the multiplication.  That is, in pseudocode,

```
if input > c
   elementwise_activation = a * (input - c)
else
   elementwise_activation = 0
```

Here is the code

```
amul = tf.mul(a,(theinput-c),name='mul-a')
```

and selection

```
result = tf.select(tf.greater(theinput,c), amul, zeros)
```

Anyway, the algorithm here is just a thoughtless experiment. Please focus just on the tensor shapes.

When run, it gives the following error from the `tf.select`:

```
ValueError: Shapes (10, 32) and (32,) must have the same rank
```

The output from the print statements is:

```
module module1 input shape= Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(10, 784), dtype=float32) 784 output size= 32

theinput shape vs nactive (10, 32) 32

a (32,) c (32,) amul (10, 32)
```

I am primarily surpised that the output of the `mul` has size (10,32) rather than size 32.
Does it mean that some variables in the graph (such as `zero` here) should include the batch size as one of the dimensions?  But other variables such as `a` do not need it?

That would be messy. I think I must be misunderstanding something.